# How to configure javah tool in Eclipse Version: 4.2.0 in windows (android NDK compilation)

Tags: eclipse, configuration, android-ndk, javah

i try to set up super simple exteranl tooling in eclispe , that is javah 
what ever i do , that means trying all the links in the web still can set it right .
and when i close the external tool config it gives me error

[image]

[image]

i tried with and without the -jni still gives me the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a valid class name: –d
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:177)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:68)
    at com.sun.tools.javah.JavahTask.run(JavahTask.java:509)
    at com.sun.tools.javah.JavahTask.run(JavahTask.java:335)
    at com.sun.tools.javah.Main.main(Main.java:46)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting up an ant task - see link

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javah.html